# "Scripting.Encoder".EncodeScriptFile() alternatives?

Tags: encryption, vbscript, cryptography, encoder

Is there another alternatives beyond [*"Scripting.Encoder"*`.EncodeScriptFile()`](http://www.jose.it-berater.org/scripting/scrrun/iscriptencoder_encodescriptfile.htm) or some other algorithm like [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#:%7E:text=AES%20is%20a%20subset%20of,during%20the%20AES%20selection%20process.&text=The%20algorithm%20described%20by%20AES,encrypting%20and%20decrypting%20the%20data.) to encrypt a **.vbs** file without corrupt your execution? or some other algorithm like  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no built-in way to encrypt/decrypt a script (ScriptEncoder only encodes which isn't encryption). You would need to provide your own form of encryption/decryption before trying to execute the script.

Comment: @user692942, then, exists other alternatives to *ScriptEncoder*, even that these only encodes (without corrupt your execution)?

Comment: Not in VBScript, No. If your asking for a recommendation for a tool or library to encrypt / decrypt VBScript then I'm afraid that is off-topic. The script engine doesn't know how to execute encrypted files, so that will never work. Like I said there is no built-in support for it.

Comment: @user692942, OK understood. Thank you.